# Why is there no `noexcept` specifier on std::unordered_map::count?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, unordered-map, noexcept

I was reading [C++ reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) about `std::unordered_map`. The 
[`empty`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/empty/) and [`size`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/size/) methods are `noexcept` qualified, but not [`count`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/count/).

I don't think it should throw in `count`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think anything's stopping the hash function or equality predicate from throwing.

Comment: Ok. I'm also wondering why [`clear`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/clear/) is `noexcept` specified. Stored instance may throw in their destructor. Why there is a different behaviour ?

Comment: @RichardDally: Destructors may not throw exceptions

Comment: @MooingDuck Destructors can throw, although it's considered poor style to do it on purpose

Comment: @M.M: I checked, you're right. They cannot throw by default, but if you explicitly mark them as `noexcept(false)` then they can throw.

Comment: It will call `std::terminate` if you throw in destructor unless you mark your destructor with `noexcept(false)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the requirements say so:

`count` returns the number of elements matching a specific key, and key comparisons are evaluated off of an object of type `X::key_type` for any unordered associative container type `X` (instantiated `std::unordered_map`s are such containers)

*n3337 23.2.5/5 [unord.req]*

> Two values `k1` and `k2` of type `Key` are considered equivalent if the container’s key equality predicate returns `true` when passed those values. ... For any two keys `k1` and `k2` in the same container, calling`pred(k1, k2)` shall always return the same value. ...

For an unordered map, `X::key_type` is defined as part of its template parameter list:

```
template<
    class Key,
    //    ^^^ member type key_type set from this parameter
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    //    ^^^^^^^^ member type key_equal set from this parameter
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

The only constraints I can find on `key_type` also apply to `value_type`:

*n3337 23.2.5/9 [unord.req]*<sup>2</sup>

> ... the requirements placed on `value_type` in Table 96 apply instead to `key_type` and `mapped_type`.

So we just need to know the requirements placed on `value_type` in table 96, which specifies the requirements for a `Container`. In the very first row, we have:

*n3337, table 96*<sup>3</sup>

> `X::value_type` | Returns `T` | *Requires:* `T` is `Destructible`

where `X` is again the type of the Container, and `T` is the type of objects it's storing. `Destructible`objects are not allowed to have throwing destructors. That's their only requirement.

*n3337, table 24*

> `u.∼T()` All resources owned by `u` are reclaimed, no exception is propagated

(`u` being an object of type `T` which fulfills the requirements of `Destructible`)

Thus, **there is no restriction on the throw guarantees offered by the key comparison function** for the `unordered_map`, and so no guarantee on the `operator==` operation provided from `std::equal_to` to implement the required behavior. The key itself lacks any such restrictions, **so: the comparison function is allowed to throw, and any function which uses the comparison function is also allowed to throw.** `count` needs to count the stored values with keys that match the supplied key with the comparison function, so it may throw.

---

`clear` may be `noexcept` because the standard bans throwing in destructors:

*17.6.4.8/1,2*<sup>4</sup> [res.on.functions]

> In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard library template components), the C++ standard library depends on components supplied by a C++ program. If these components do not meet their requirements, the Standard places no requirements on the implementation.
>
> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> ...
>
> - if any replacement function or handler function or **destructor operation exits via an exception**, unless specifically allowed in the applicable *Required behavior:* paragraph.
>
> ...

since the only client-dependent code `clear` executes may not throw exceptions, and the implementation doesn't need to, it may be and has been marked `noexcept`

---

Notes:

<sup>1. The n4140 standard draft (near c++14) does not appear to have changed this clause at all.</sup>

<sup>2. n4140 retains this phrasing, moved to clause 10 from clause 9.</sup>

<sup>3. The `Container` requirements are also listed in Table 96 of n4140, and list the requirement for `T` as being [`Erasable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Erasable), which also places no restrictions on `operator==`</sup>

<sup>4. The wording of this clause hasn't changed in n4140.</sup>

Comment: [res.on.functions]/2.4 bans throwing destructors across the board and has done so since at least C++03.

Comment: @T.C. fixed. Thank you again for giving me the clause.